# SQL Query does not like alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

Still learning SQL and using MS SQL to execute HackerRank [problem 4](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-4/problem?isFullScreen=true).

Why does this error? I

```
with cname as (
select 
    (count(city) - count(distinct city) as citycount
from station
)
    
select
    citycount
from cname
```

Error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server dbrank-tsql, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

Comment: Count your left/right parathesis; they have different counts.

Comment: Just a question, why do you need a cte, just select would do

Comment: I'm trying to learn SQL, and so picked a hard topic - CTE and decided I'm going to use this approach wherever I can so I can become comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one of the paranthesis after `distinct city)`.

Try this:

```
with cname as (
select 
    (count(city) - count(distinct city)) as citycount
from station
)
    
select
    citycount
from cname
```

Even you don't need starting and ending paranthesis around expression.

```
SELECT count(city) - count(distinct city) as citycount FROM STATION
```

Comment: @Dan the error is actually pretty accurate in my opinion. *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'."* and your error *is* near `AS`; you were missing the right parenthesis that needed to go directly before it. I suppose you could read that the left parenthesis at the start of the line was superfluous, but the error still tells you exactly where the problem of parsing the SQL occurs.